# Chain homotopy equivalent complexes: A computation

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $A_\bullet := 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ where
$$
f_{a,b}(t) := (a,b)\cdot t \quad \text{and} \quad g_{c,d}((x,y)) = cx + dy,
$$
for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to find out those values $a,b,c,d$ for which the chain complex $A_\bullet$ is chain homotopically equivalent to the trivial complex. We can phrase the question as follows:

**Q.** For which $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, is the zero map $0$ a chain homotopy equivalence between $A_\bullet$ and $B_\bullet := 0_\bullet$?

Since $\operatorname{id}_{B_\bullet} = 0$, it is clear that if $f: B_\bullet \to A_\bullet$ is a chain homotopic inverse to $0$, then $f \circ 0 = 0 = \operatorname{id}_{B_\bullet}$, so this, in particular, $f \circ 0 \simeq \operatorname{id}_{B_\bullet}$. The second condition requires that $0 \circ f = 0 \cong \operatorname{id}_{A_\bullet}$. Let us examine the case in more detail.

Assume $P_\bullet: A_\bullet \to A_\bullet$ is a chain homotopy from $0$ to $\operatorname{id}_{A_\bullet}$, that is
[image]

Now, at each position $n$, we have the chain homotopy equation which yields
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}} &= P_2 \circ f_{a,b}\\
\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}} &= f_{a,b} \circ P_2 + P_1 \circ g_{c,d}\\
\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}} &= g_{c,d} \circ P_1.
\end{align*}

Precomposing the second line with $f_{a,b}$ and postcomposing with $g_{c,d}$, we have

$$
g_{c,d} \circ f_{a,b} = g_{c,d} \circ f_{a,b} \circ \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}} + \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z}} \circ g_{c,d} \circ f_{a,b}.
$$
Hence, $g_{c,d} \circ f_{a,b} = 2 g_{c,d} \circ f_{a,b}$, from which I conclude that $g_{c,d} \circ f_{a,b} = 0$. But this I already knew, since $A_\bullet$ is a complex. I am a bit confused. How else one would go about answering **Q**?

Comment: For $A_{\bullet}$ to be homotopy-equivalent to the trivial complex, it is necessary that its homology groups vanish. Taking that into account might simplify your calculations.

Comment: It's also necessary that $ac + bd = 0$ for this to be a chain complex at all.